# Geomesa WPS tubeselect error

Tags: geoserver, geomesa

I am running geoserver 2.9.4 from this [image](http://quay.io/geomesa/geoserver) and I am trying to get the [tubeselect](http://www.geomesa.org/documentation/tutorials/geomesa-tubeselect.html) example working, because I need to show how points move through time. My WPS request is the following:

```
<ows:Identifier>gs:Import</ows:Identifier>
<wps:DataInputs>
  <wps:Input>
    <ows:Identifier>features</ows:Identifier>
    <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wps" method="POST">
      <wps:Body>
        <wps:Execute version="1.0.0" service="WPS">
          <ows:Identifier>geomesa:TubeSelect</ows:Identifier>
          <wps:DataInputs>
            <wps:Input>
              <ows:Identifier>tubeFeatures</ows:Identifier>
              <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wfs" method="POST">
                <wps:Body>
                  <wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.0.0" outputFormat="GML2" xmlns:geomesa="geomesa">
                    <wfs:Query typeName="geomesa:posicion"/>
                  </wfs:GetFeature>
                </wps:Body>
              </wps:Reference>
            </wps:Input>
            <wps:Input>
              <ows:Identifier>featureCollection</ows:Identifier>
              <wps:Reference mimeType="text/xml" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wfs" method="POST">
                <wps:Body>
                  <wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.0.0" outputFormat="GML2" xmlns:geomesa="geomesa">
                    <wfs:Query typeName="geomesa:posicion"/>
                  </wfs:GetFeature>
                </wps:Body>
              </wps:Reference>
            </wps:Input>
            <wps:Input>
              <ows:Identifier>maxSpeed</ows:Identifier>
              <wps:Data>
                <wps:LiteralData>55</wps:LiteralData>
              </wps:Data>
            </wps:Input>
            <wps:Input>
              <ows:Identifier>maxTime</ows:Identifier>
              <wps:Data>
                <wps:LiteralData>120</wps:LiteralData>
              </wps:Data>
            </wps:Input>
          </wps:DataInputs>
          <wps:ResponseForm>
            <wps:RawDataOutput mimeType="text/xml; subtype=wfs-collection/1.0">
              <ows:Identifier>result</ows:Identifier>
            </wps:RawDataOutput>
          </wps:ResponseForm>
        </wps:Execute>
      </wps:Body>
    </wps:Reference>
  </wps:Input>
  <wps:Input>
    <ows:Identifier>coverage</ows:Identifier>
    <wps:Reference mimeType="image/tiff" xlink:href="http://geoserver/wcs" method="POST">
      <wps:Body/>
    </wps:Reference>
  </wps:Input>
  <wps:Input>
    <ows:Identifier>workspace</ows:Identifier>
    <wps:Data>
      <wps:LiteralData>geomesa</wps:LiteralData>
    </wps:Data>
  </wps:Input>
  <wps:Input>
    <ows:Identifier>store</ows:Identifier>
    <wps:Data>
      <wps:LiteralData>posiciones</wps:LiteralData>
    </wps:Data>
  </wps:Input>
  <wps:Input>
    <ows:Identifier>name</ows:Identifier>
    <wps:Data>
      <wps:LiteralData>posiciones-current</wps:LiteralData>
    </wps:Data>
  </wps:Input>
  <wps:Input>
    <ows:Identifier>srs</ows:Identifier>
    <wps:Data>
      <wps:LiteralData>EPSG:4326</wps:LiteralData>
    </wps:Data>
  </wps:Input>
</wps:DataInputs>
  <wps:ResponseForm>
    <wps:RawDataOutput>
      <ows:Identifier>layerName</ows:Identifier>
    </wps:RawDataOutput>
  </wps:ResponseForm>
</wps:Execute>
```

But when I execute the WPS process, I got the following error:

```
<ows:ExceptionText>Unrecognized request type {}</ows:ExceptionText>
```

My setup is geomesa 1.3.2 with apache accumulo as DataStore. My datastore is geomesa:posiciones

Any idea?

Comment: How are you executing the WPS against geoserver?

Comment: I am using postman to send the POST request to the <geoserver host>/geoserver/wps endpoint. Is this correct?

Comment: did you copy paste the whole XML file? it should start with a `<wps:Execute>`

Comment: Yes, the payload I am sending starts with <wps:Execute>

Answer (score 1):

You might need to specify the content-type header - in curl it would be something like:

```
curl -X POST -d @my-request.xml 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wps' -H 'Content-Type: text/xml'
```